# Can't access NIfi after successful start

Tags: macos, apache-nifi

After what appears to be a successful start:

```
nifi run
INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
...
INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 14532
```

I still cannot access the application at the (default) assigned address `127.0.0.1:8443/nifi/`

Checking the app logs via `cat nifi-app.log` in the homebrew install directory, I can see that it again appears to be available:

```
INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started. The UI is available at the following URLs:
INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer https://127.0.0.1:8443/nifi
```

Chrome will either say that it can't connect at all or "localhost didn’t send any data"

But I still can't connect. What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

At least when using Safari or Chrome, it appears I just needed to wait on the non-loading page for several minutes after the logs reported it was available - only then did I receive the expected "this is unsafe" message, where you can accept the cert and move on with your life

Edit: I now think that I HAVE to access the site via Safari at least once before I can see it in Chrome.